# *ngIf getting error on block that get false

Tags: angular

I have simple template with *ngIf where it gets false I can see that my app is failing on this block of template with

> Error: Template parse errors:(…)(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:42150ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308

my ngIf is false but I can see it throwing errors on the block that true...

this is my template :

```
 <div *ngIf=userData.isAuth>
<div class="user-profile clearfix">
  <div class="dropdown al-user-profile">
    <a class="profile-toggle-link dropdown-toggle" id="user-profile-dd" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="{{ (userData.user.name| userData.user.avatar ) }}"> //the problem line
```

my component:

```
  constructor(private _state:GlobalState,userData:UserData) {
    this._state.subscribe('menu.isCollapsed', (isCollapsed) => {
      this.isMenuCollapsed = isCollapsed;
    });
  }
```

and service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  user = {};  //geting populated by function
  isAuth = false;
```

Comment: Is there additional information with the error message. Did you add `CommonModule` to `imports: []` of the `@NgModule()` the component is part of?

Comment: Add the complete message not only `...` and Show the complete templste. Make sure that all opening tags are closed

Comment: the issuw when I delete <img src="{{ (userData.user.name| userData.user.avatar ) }}"> all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking [example ng 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) saw better solution with no need to check on template...

```
export class BaPageTop implements OnInit{
  public userdata:UserData;
  constructor(private _state:GlobalState,public userData:UserData) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userdata=this.userData;
```

}

and the template is

```
<div *ngIf="userdata.isAuth">
    <div class="user-profile clearfix">...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all fix your `ngIf` attribute with quotes:

```
*ngIf="userData?.isAuth"
```

The problem is, that `|` is used for [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) in templates and the avatar certainly is not a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html). So you don't state what you wanted to achieve with the pipe, but maybe this does what you want:

```html
<img src="{{userData.user?.name}}/{{userData.user?.avatar}}"/>
```

Comment: Come on, that's an easy one. It tells you, the `userData` object is not loaded yet. Just add the `?`. I update my post ...

Comment: strange for me that I need to check userData?.isAuth because its not geting to any reset service.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` is a self closing tag. Change to:

```
<img src="{{ (userData.user.name| userData.user.avatar ) }}"/>
```

Comment: ok this one fix but stll getting same. whey its going to this if its false? whey it should care if data on user is define or not?

Comment: Use `userData?.user?.Name` so it is ok if user Data is empty. And of course user

Comment: The template is parsed in all cases. It do not depends on if the code is used or not. The error Comes at compile time. Not at runtime

Answer (score -1):

I think you are getting error because `userData.user.name` is not valid image URL so check after changing img tag as below :

```
<img [src]="userData.user.avatar" [alt]="userData.user.name"/>
```

Make sure that value of `userData.user.avatar` will be the valid image URL value.

Comment: but the ngif is false why its matter?

Comment: change `*ngIf=userData.isAuth` to `*ngIf="userData.isAuth"` and check it.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `""` to `*ngIf`

```
 *ngIf="userData.isAuth"
```

please remove `()` inside image tag :

```
  <img src="{{userData.user.name| userData.user.avatar }}">
```

Comment: @Jens the template parse error gets removed : `Error: Template parse errors:(…)(anonymous function) `